# PHP array to string issue

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have an array in PHP when I print it it is like that :

```
["Testing","Test2","New Testing Activity","The last five letters in the alphabet"]
```

is there a way to make the array like that :

```
{"Testing","Test2","New Testing Activity","The last five letters in the alphabet"}
```

I want this `'{'` instead of `'['`

Thanks

Comment: This isnt a array structure in PHP. Please show us your code and tell us what you want to do to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Maybe* you want to do:

```
echo '{"' . implode('","', $arr) . '"}';
```

Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/p57-0u4

Comment: Exactly what I was putting together! Nice job, @qwertynl!